# Passing a thread queue object as a object variable in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety

I am writing a package which takes  inputs like thread count,thread::Queue objects.
Once the package object is created, I will create the threads based on the input argument and dequeue the input queue in each thread and each threads executes a simple unix command like pinging to a server(changed to keep it simple).
Below is the code:

```
my $failed_q = Thread::Queue -> new();
my $success_q = Thread::Queue -> new();
my $process_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

package WorkerThreads;


sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {
      _ThreadCount => shift,
      _FidQueue => shift,
      _SuccessQueue  => shift,
      _FailedQueue => shift,
   };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}

sub WorkerProcess
{
  my ($self)=@_;

  while ( my $fid = $self->{_FidQueue} -> dequeue() )
  {
    chomp ( $fid );
    print threads -> self() -> tid(). ": pinging $fid\n";
    my $result = `/bin/ping -c 1 $fid`;
    if ( $? ) { $self->{_FailedQueue} -> enqueue ( $fid ) }
    else { $self->{_SuccessQueue} -> enqueue ( $fid ) ; }
    sleep 1;
  }
 print threads -> self() -> tid(). ":\n";
}


sub CreateThreads
{
    my ($self)=@_;
    my $Num_of_threads=$self->{_ThreadCount};

    for ( 1..$Num_of_threads )
    {
      threads -> create ( \&WorkerProcess );
    }

}

sub StartThreads
{
my ($self)=@_;

    foreach my $thr ( threads -> list() )
    {
      $thr -> join();
    }
}

sub PrintResult
{
my ($self)=@_;


     while ( my $fid = $self->{_FailedQueue} -> dequeue_nb() )
     {
       print "$fid failed to ping\n";
     }

     #collate results. ('synchronise' operation)

     while ( my $fid = $self->{_SuccessQueue} -> dequeue_nb() )
     {
       print "$fid Ping Succeeded\n";
     }

}
sub ProcessRequest
{
 my ($self)=@_;

 $self->CreateThreads(@_);
 $self->StartThreads(@_);
 $self->PrintResult(@_);

}

package main;

#insert tasks into thread queue.
open ( my $input_fh, "<", "server_list" ) or die $!;
$process_q->enqueue( <$input_fh> );
close ( $input_fh );


my $Workers;

$Workers=WorkerThreads->new(
                            10,
                            $process_q,
                            $success_q, 
                            $failed_q
                          );

$Workers->ProcessRequest();
```

I am getting an error while i try to dequeue in the while loop that queue is undefined. So i got this doubt like can we pass a thread queue object to a package as an argument.

```
Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Can't call method "dequeue" on an undefined value at .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a function into `threads->create` without any context of which object they are working within. Something like this should work

```
threads->create( sub { $self->WorkerProcess } );
```

Comment: or `async { $self->WorkerProcess };`